# Naming conventions for hierarchical roles in an application

Tags: design, web-applications, user-story, file-structure, roles

I'm creating an application that internally will have have three totally different separated areas of interfaces.
- One where users create content and interact with each other
- One where one person invites the above users and administers her organization's account
- One where several people are administers the whole application

Is `User`, `Admin` and `SuperAdmin` the convention for the above? I particularly dislike `User`, as everyone touching the application is a user.

The application will be handed over to other people once in production so I want these roles/user areas to make sense for other programmers aswell.

Comment: Your role names must be meaningful to the participants from a business perspective.  That's your naming convention.  It would be nice if the organization of the names made sense as well, but that also derives from a business domain perspective.  In other words, if your role is "document manager," then that's what your permission should be called.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to guess your domain where more specific roles can be found. Some generic variants though:

1. Anonymous
2. Member or Editor or Content editor or just User (why not?)
3. Manager or User manager (if restricted only to dealing with users, not content). It may also be Group manager, if restricted to some group of users
4. Administrator or Superadmin(*)

(*) I'd reserved Superadmin for a multi-tenant system. And superadmin can create organizations and do similar tasks. Maybe it is your case, maybe not.

Do not forget, that role is something, which may be contextual (local roles). Also, user might have several roles at the same time and context. So, User may be the least specific role, while the user may have Editor or Manager role.

It is probably good idea to make role/permission system one bit more flexible than current requirements are.

**Edit**: Let me stress once more, that naming should come as a result of the domain itself. Domain analysis in some form should be performed for any software project, common names and language established, ideally, same language between developers and other stakeholders. Usually problem domain names are used (because those are more likely to be correctly understood by users). In some cases using solution domain concepts may be inevitable.